# Redis insertion lag for sorted sets

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am trying to push a small amount of data (about 50 bytes) from my application (written in Java using the jedis driver) into a sorted set with about 360 members (each member also contains a very small amount of data). I am experiencing a 60-90 second lag time between my application making the insert and seeing the result on my redis server (a separate server in a different data center). This happens consistently. At first I thought there was something in my application causing the query to hang and then execute a minute later, but that's not the case because I can shut my application server down entirely immediately after running the query and the new item still shows up a minute later in Redis. In addition, when I removed all elements of the set and tried the insert again, it happened immediately (which is the intended behavior).

This is entirely in a test environment with no other traffic hitting either server, and my Redis server hardly has any data in it and has plenty of ram and cpu. Latency between my application server and the redis server is approx ~50ms.

Is there a configuration setting that I'm missing that could be causing such a delay?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is my code for inserting

```
public void save(RedisEntity entity) {
    String key = entity.getKey();
    String value = entity.getValue();
    Jedis jedis = database.getJedis();

    try {
        if (entity instanceof RedisListEntity) {
            if (((RedisListEntity)entity).isSavePushesLeft()) {
                jedis.lpush(key, value);
            } else {
                jedis.rpush(key, value);
            }
        } else if (entity instanceof RedisSortedSetEntity) {
            Long score = ((RedisSortedSetEntity)entity).getScore();
            jedis.zadd(key, score, value);
        } else if (entity instanceof RedisSetEntity) {
            jedis.sadd(key, value);
        } else {
            jedis.set(key, value);
        }
    } catch (JedisConnectionException e) {
        raiseErrorForSave(key, value);
        database.returnBrokenResourceToPool(jedis);
    } finally {
        database.returnResourceToPool(jedis);
    }
}
```

And retrieval (although keep in mind the key doesn't show up in redis-cli on the redis server for 1-2 minutes after insertion, so this code was never even part of the problem):

```
public Set<String> getSortedSetMembersWithRangeRankRev(String key, double min, double max, int start, int size) {
    Set<String> result = null;
    Jedis jedis = database.getJedis();

    try {
        result = jedis.zrevrangeByScore(key, max, min, start, size);
    } catch (JedisConnectionException e) {
        logger.warn("Failed to retrieve set for key " + key);
        logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        database.returnBrokenResourceToPool(jedis);
    } finally {
        database.returnResourceToPool(jedis);
    }
    return result;
}
```

EDIT: Some more info - I restarted my Redis server after it had been on for a few days (with almost no traffic as it is in a development environment) and updates seem to be coming through instantaneously as the set reaches 1000 members. This problem is still troubling for me though and I would like to identify the cause and prevent it from happening in the future - until then I cannot release this into a production environment.

Comment: Can you post your java code with jedis interaction for write and for read?

Comment: Yes just added the code

Comment: Do you have some logs to show? If not, I recommend using a supervision on redis, there are many such as RedisLive or redis-munin, supervisord...

Comment: Not at this time. Thank you, I will try that and let you know if I find new information.